# Call for Class Code in a jxchange Acct Inq?

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

I need to call for the Class code of an account instead of the Product Code in an AcctInq call.  How can I find the name the variable for Class Code on the system?

I tried the word Class

Answer (score 0):

Carly,

The information provided below is for the SilverLake core. Based on the information provided we are unsure of which core to provide information, so we elected for the most common.

We believe that the element name you are seeking is AcctClsfCode the Xmapping for a DDA account is DepAcctInqRec.x_DepInfoRec.DepInfoRec.AcctClsfCode. We searched for the word "class" on this mapping page. - https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/core-services/acctinq/providers/silverlake/mapping/.

Thank you,

John